# (python) add elements in consecutive rows if the condition holds true

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, rows

I have a list with "N" rows and "3" columns. If the first two elements of consecutive rows are same, then I want to add the elements in the third column and return a single line with the added "third column" value.

e.g.

```
120.638000      -21.541700      0.3  
120.638000      -21.541700      0.8       
121.331001      -21.795500      0.5       
120.688004      -21.587400      0.1        
120.688004      -21.587400      0.5      
120.688004      -21.587400      0.9     
121.525002      -21.504200      0.9
```

to

```
120.638000      -21.541700      1.1  (add third column of row 1 and 2)       
121.331001      -21.795500      0.5       
120.688004      -21.587400      1.5  (sum(0.1,0.5,0.9))       
121.525002      -21.504200      0.9
```

Any suggestions for implementing this in python?

Comment: That example doesn't look like a list. Do you really have a list, or do  you have all the content in a tab-separated file?

Comment: I have this content in a tab-separated file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read your data in using `csvreader` then you can use a defaultdict to sum up column3 based on identical tuples in column1,2:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from csv import csvreader

result = defaultdict(float)
with open("<datafile>") as f:
    data = csvreader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for a,b,c in data:
        result[(a,b)] += float(c)

for (a,b),c in result.items():
    print(a, b, c)
```

This wont necessarily come out in the same order as dicts are not sorted.

Comment: Your previous program worked perfectly !! Thank you so much. I am using data=loadtxt('file') to read my file and 'defaultdict' works perfectly well. The only problem is that it is not in the exact order, but that should not be a problem for my work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the library `csv` to generate a list of rows.

Use a dictionary keys to maintain unique pairs of columns 1-2 values. Aggregate the total values for the third column in the dictionary values.

```
totals = {}
for (a,b,c) in list_of_rows:
    if (a,b) in totals:
        totals[(a,b)] += c
    else:
        totals[(a,b)] = c
```

If you want the results in a list of 3-element lists,

```
totals_list = [[key[0], key[1], totals[key]] for key in totals]
```

I think it's not reliable to count on equality for floats. If the precision is always the same as indicated in your example data -- and I didn't care enough about processing time to warrant investigating -- I might use

`for (int(a*1e6), int(b*1e6), c) in list_of_rows:` to feel more confident about my method.

Comment: Thank you everyone for very quick responses. The program provided by @achampion worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator
import itertools
with open('blah') as infile, open('blahout', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
    for k,group in itertools.groupby(csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t'), operator.itemgetter(0,1)):
        writer.writerow(list(k) + [sum(float(r[-1]) for r in group)])
```